# Prove that these two sets have the same cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $Z$ be a finite set of $n$ points. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a class of arbitrary sets. Is it true that these two classes of sets have the same cardinality $$ |\left\{Z \cap A: A \in \mathcal{A} \right\}|=|\left\{Z \cap A^c: A \in \mathcal{A} \right\}|?$$

It is not true that they have the same sets, but I can see in my head that they do share the same cadinality, but I'm struggle with giving a rigorous proof. Since these classes are finite (because $Z$ is finite) it's enough to see that there is a bijection, but I can't find it. I was thinking using the fact that giving a set $A$ there is one and only one complement $A^c$ but I'm not sure.
Thanks

Comment: Doesn't it follows form the fact that ${\cal A}$ and ${\cal A}':=\{A^c:\ A\in{\cal A}\}$ share cardinal?

Answer (score 1):

Both classes are collections of subsets of $Z$.  And for any subset $S$ of $Z$, $S$ is in the first class if and only if $Z \setminus S$ is in the second class.